# jquery toggle disable click

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I have a menu at the click of every item I display a div with 'toggle' function, what I try to do is click on the menu item disabiletare the already selected or clicked. The code I used is as follows.

```
$(function() {
    $("#pul-m1").click(function() {
      $('#box-company').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 800);
      });
     $('#pul-m1').unbind(click);
     });
```

where 'pul-m1' click to toggle the div opens with 'box-company' pop-up from the left;
when the div is opened I would like the button just clicked on the menu (pul-m1) is disabled.

with the code I created the click continues to function by activating the toggle, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use slideToggle,and if you want only single click and to disable clicked item.just use .one function of jquery

```
<script>

    $(function() { 
    $('#box-company').hide();  
    $("#pul-m1").one('click',function(e) {  

     $('#box-company').slideToggle({ direction: 'left' }, 800); 
      });

     }); 

</script>
```